# iOS App not displayed under "New" category in App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I got the update of my iOS App approved on saturday. I immediately released it after it was approved (had it holding for developer release), and then it remained in the "Processing for App Store" state for about 12 hours.

When it was "Ready for sale", it was nowhere showing in the App Store under "New"?! I searched every category it was assigned to and it didn't appear anywhere.

So, my question is: What could be the reason?

- Does changing the icon/category/whatever metadata influence the processing duration and therefor the probability that it's still displayed under "New"?
- Is it because my App was processing so long for App Store that it got pushed down the "New" queue?
- Does "Hold for developer release" have something to do with it?
- Or is it just that new Apps aren't always displayed under "New"?

I'd really like to know how Apps get into the "New" category and what I could have possibly done that my App totally skipped this part.

Comment: Sounds like you just updated an existing app. Otherwise I didn't know that there is an 'Hold for developer release' on first release. Updates aren't displayed in the 'New' section.

Comment: Are you sure? Since when? How would you push your App sales once the App has drowned in the store? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps in the 'New' section are sorted by date of the approval of the first release. Updates aren't in the 'New' section. If you want to promote your app you will have to use the traditional way with paid advertisements. Because only with a couple of downloads you will get in another section like 'Top Downloads' or 'Top Revenue'.
Another trick to push app downloads for free is to reduce it's price for about a week, because there are a couple of tools and web services which highlight price drops in the app store.

Comment: Well that's odd. In the old App Store, your App would be pushed on top whenever updated. Thanks for your useful tips though!